# How To make the tab bar/address bar thinner on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, settings, macos

I'm looking for a way to reduce the header space that chrome requires. On Safari, the tab bar is quite thin, compared to chrome where it's about 1.5x larger. Is there any way to reduce the height of either the tab bar or address bar, or both on Chrome in macOS?

Comment: The same question on Mac.

Comment: You mean Safari?

Comment: non, chrome on mac!